# Debian package with dependency to package in unconfigured PPA

Tags: dependencies, ppa, deb, packaging

I'm creating a debian package `primary.deb` (custom, home-made package for internal use) that depends on `secondary.deb` (hosted in external PPA).

I'd like the users of `primary.deb` to not explicitly have to add the PPA to their package manager by running a command before installing it. Is there a way to pre-download `secondary.deb`, include it in `primary.deb` and have it automatically installed during the installation of `primary.deb`?

There is a [similar question from 2014](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378467/can-a-deb-package-contain-a-ppa-dependency-and-install-packages-from-the-ppa) that answers this question with no. However, almost 7 years have passed and I'm wondering if the situation changed.

Comment: No, it hasn't changed. The standard way to ask for an update is to post a bounty (outdated answers is one of the standard bounty reasons)

Comment: Why can't you add the secondary Deb file to your repository?

Comment: Thanks @muru. I just added a bounty to the original question.

Comment: I don't have a PPA at the moment and want to figure out whether there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Not really. The simplest way would be to include the files of the dependency inside your package. The next best is to make a repo and out both packages in them.